# passing json object to view and displaying in slickgrid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, slickgrid

The other posts on this topic have helped me but not completely. I am retrieving data from a Wcf service (included in my MVC 4 project) like this:

WarehouseController.cs

```
WarehouseInput objWI = new WarehouseInput();
  
    public ActionResult Index(WarehouseInput value)
    {           
        objWI.count = 15;
        objWI.offset = 0;
        objWI.query = "";
        objWI.sort = "ID";
        objWI.order = "asc";
        objWI.ID = 0;
        objWI.RowID = 0;
        Service1 c = new Service1();
        c.GetWarehouseList(objWI);
        //var model = c.GetServices();
    update 1  ----->      return View(objWI);
        //return GetWarehouseList(objWI);
  update 2  ----->     //return Json(objWI, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I am getting the data in my Json object...

[image: data fetched]

Index.cshtml
EDIT:

```
  @model MvcApplication1.WS.DataContracts.WarehouseInput

 @{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

 <h2>Index</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">
alert('0');
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Index")',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function(resp) {
            alert(resp);
            if (resp.WarehouseResults != null) {
                var objTemp = resp.WarehouseResults;

                            //var from = resp.offset, to = from + resp.WarehouseResults.length;
                            //data.length = parseInt(resp.total);
                            //for (var i = 0; i < resp.WarehouseResults.length; i++) {
                            //    data[from + i] = resp.WarehouseResults[i];
                            //    data[from + i].index = from + i;
                            //}
                            //$("#lblRows").html("<b>Total: " + resp.total + "</b>");
                            //onDataLoaded.notify({ from: from, to: to });
                        }
                        else {
                            //i = indicators.pop();
                            //if (i != null)
                            //    i.fadeOut();
                            alert('Error loading the page');
                        }
            alert('1');
        }
    });
alert('1.5');
var values = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.WarehouseResults));
var data = [];

var grid;
var validator;
```

The problem is that the control never goes to the cshtml. How do I pass the json object to the view (UI)? How do I display it in the slickgrid that I am using?
EDIT: The javascript code needs to be revised, but first I have to get the control to reach there.

Comment: When you say "control never goes to the cshtml", does that mean that the `success` function passed to `$.getJSON` isn't being called?  If that's the case, then a) you have a server-side error, or b) you can try putting the javascript in a `<script>` element.

Comment: yes thats what I mean...

Comment: Use the F12 developer tools in the browser, and watch the network traffic to see what, if any, result is coming back from the web server.  Also, verify that the url you are using works (by pasting it in a web browser).

Comment: I am getting the desired result from the server. I am just unable to bind it to the grid and display it.

Comment: Has slickgrid been initialized by the point in time that the data has been returned? i'm not entirely sure how that control works.  I'm assuming that the data variable and the onDataLoaded.notify methods are hooks into that control.

Comment: For now, slickgrid can be ignored. I need to get the data (list) in the success function. I am getting the whole page in the resp object.

Comment: In case you're confused here... a Razor View creates an HTML file on the server on the fly and sends it as a response to the HTTP request.  So when the action is called, you collect the data from your data source (DB/web service), populate it into a strongly typed view (list of models etc.), then pass it to a View function.  Then your Razor code can embed the models in the page in however format you want (HTML tags, JSON string)...

Comment: The alternative to all of that is to have your server return a more or less empty view and do everything in JavaScript.  Your JavaScript calls a web service, and takes the JSON result and populates HTML on the fly using that.  This is a bit more difficult but it has the advantage of being able to load (or save) data at any time based on user events (eg. user clicks a refresh button) without reloading the page.

Comment: In your question you were doing both methods.  You should let us one which one you require.

Comment: May be I am not able to explain it to you. I'll try again: I get my desired result in the controller(plz see update 1). From there, I push the data out to the view. The problem is I dont know how to receive the data in the view. How & where do I receive it??

Comment: Your ViewModel is in a class called Model.  You can write code such as "@foreach (var warehouse in Model.WarehouseResults) { <li>@warehouse.Name</li> }" as an example to generate an <li> tag with the names of each warehouse in your view model.

Comment: Ok, let me try that...

Comment: and I'll be removing the ajax call, rt.??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35602/discussion-between-stylojack-10-and-moozhe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a View, not a JSON.  You have a line commented out which does what you want:

```
return View(objWI.WarehouseResults);
```

You have another line in your cshtml file which turns that into JSON, which you have also commented out:

```
var values = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.WarehouseResults));
```

What I don't understand is why you are calling GetWarehouseList in the action method and also in the JavaScript?

Calling services from JavaScript is great for reloading data without having to load the page.  But are you really trying to do that?  You're only calling it on JQuery.ready which is once when the page loads.  But when you load the page you can already embed the JSON in the HTML with the ViewModel.

stylojack_10:
"while this may not be the answer, I finally got the answer in our discussion, hence I am marking this as the answer."

Comment: As I said the javascript code needs revision. 
Anyway, now I have uncommented the 2 lines & I get alert('0') (see EDIT 2) called. How do I go furhter?

Comment: The MVC `Json` method returns a 'JsonResult', which is an 'ActionResult', so that's not a problem.

Comment: You have the data in the view.  What do you want to do with it?  Your data is in a variable called "values" in JavaScript.  You said you want to use a slickgrid.  I don't know the specifics of how to use it and its github page isn't working for me now, but that's the only piece of the puzzle left.

Comment: You can remove most of your JavaScript except for the line where you create the "values" variable, then write a single JQuery.ready function which populates the grid.  Get rid of the AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

You can Make an Ajax Call From javascript and bind the result received  to slick grid,

Your Ajax Call as folows,

```
    $.getJSON("ActionName", success = function (data) {
    //Your Code to bind slick grid data
});
```

And You Action Will be as follows,

```
        public ContentResult ActionName()
    {
        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(YourObject, serializerSettings);
        return Content(jsonString);
    }
```